# Oracle OAM DefaultOperationalApproval workflow human task subscribe events

Tags: oracle, events, soa, bpel, oam

How can I subscribe to Default OAM approval task(DefaultOperationalApproval) via soa composite. I.e. I want to send SMS/Email OnTaskAssigned event.

**Steps I have used but not working-**

1. Created a MDS connection to my soa server(SOA-MDS)
2. Created a soa composite project.
3. Added a bpel process and Selected Template Subscribe to Events

   3.1 For event selection

   ```
   -> Click on + gree icon
   -> Select Event definition file
   -> go to resource palette 
   -> Select SOA-MDS connection
   -> soa->shared->workflow
   -> Select HumanTaskEvent.edl
   -> Ok
   ```
4. Done some stuff inside my BPEL & deployed the composite

Inside Flow Trace Event is not getting subscribed to OAM task assignment. Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution!
Actually I need to Mark Check on respective workflow event trigger under Human Task Events tab. And that'smade my event subscription working for human task:

[image: k10gaurav- Human Task Event Subscribe]